# The specified @job_id does not exist

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm running this code, c#, .net5

```cs
void DropDatabase(string name)
{
    var sql = $@"
        if (select DB_ID('{name}')) is not null
        begin
            alter database [{name}] set offline with rollback immediate;
            alter database [{name}] set online;
            drop database [{name}];
        end";
    
    using var conn = new SqlConnection("redacted connection string");
    conn.Open();
    conn.InfoMessage += (o, m) => Console.WriteLine(m.Message);
        
    using var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But I get the following error

```
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The specified @job_id ('9B58E19A-5F66-4C6C-896B-B801DD29E57C') does not exist.
 Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.
 Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I don't think that my query is causing this error, and I'm not being able to pinpoint the cause.
The only thing I can find online related to this error is this.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51290/the-specified-job-id-does-not-exist

The solution there is to restart SQLAgent, which I'm not able to do right now.

Three questions

1. How to get to the root cause of this error? Am I right assuming my query is not the cause?
2. How to fix this error? What does it mean?
3. Could I possibly ignore the error?

Comment: Does the database have any DDL triggers on it? (or server level DDL trigger on `ALTER_DATABASE`)

Comment: Do note that syntax like `DB_ID('{name}')` and `database [{name}]`  are *wide* open to injection attacks. The former should be parametrised, and the latter should be being properly quoted and escaped; just wrapping it in brackets (`[]`) isn't enough.

Comment: @MartinSmith, many triggers none DDL (that I know of). How would that relate to the problem?

Comment: @Larnu Consider this pseudo-code

Comment: "How would that relate to the problem?"  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW43Z.png

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you! I will search for ddl triggers.

Comment: I'm seeing some results from select * from dbo.sysjobs that I didn't expect.
still digging

Answer (score 0):

From @MartinSmith's suggestion I discovered that I had CDC enabled.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/change-data-capture-stored-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

By not enabling CDC, this error is gone.
Another option is to disable it after the fact
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-disable-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16